# How to use XAML Window.Resources just one one element and not on all elements on the whole Window

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, user-interface, resources

I followed the instruction on https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf to install ModernWpfUI in VisualStudio 2022. It's working well, but i can´t figure out, how to use the ui:Elements parallel to the Common WPF Elements, without restyling them to the modern UI. I think the example will explain my problem.

For example, in this case the "normal" Button will also be affected by the ui:Elements Style:

```
<Window x:Class="MoniCA_DQ200_CFD.Views.test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MoniCA_DQ200_CFD.Views"
        xmlns:ui="http://schemas.modernwpf.com/2019"
        ui:WindowHelper.UseModernWindowStyle="True"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Test Window" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ui:ThemeResources/>
                <ui:XamlControlsResources/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <Button>Button Text</Button> <!--This Button should not affected by the ModernWpfUI Style because it´s a common WPF Element-->
        <ui:ToggleSwitch></ui:ToggleSwitch> <!--This TogleSwitch from ui:Elements is working well-->
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

[Picture of GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOLly.png)

Can you tell me, why the ui Style also changes the Style of the non ui:Element?

Best Regards
Tim